# Convert datatype from list in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of 3000 elements, each of it of the size `(1, 60, 60)` and would like to get in in one element (without a list) with the dimension `(3000, 1, 60, 60)`. Can someone help me?
I tried

```
a= []
for i in range(0, len(b)):
    a.append(b[i])
```

But then I got a list again

Comment: Please post some sample data and / or the code you have tried.

Comment: You essentially mean list of those 3000 elements. Just iterate over those elements and append the items to a new list.

Comment: @Clarissa just use "edit" for your post and put information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array(b)
a=np.reshape(a,(3000, 1, 60, 60))
```